# asp.net how to use list Item Clicked Event UserDetails.aspx

Tags: asp.net, sql, events, listitem

When the list item is clicked then i want it to redirect to

```
      UserDetails.aspx?Id=" + Session["UserId"].ToString());
```

.  I tryed

```
<li class="active "><a href="~/UserDetails.aspx?Id=" + Session["UserId"].ToString());"><span>Home</span></a></li>
```

But it doesnt work?

Answer (score 1):

Make anchor tag runat="server" and try this

```
<li class="active ">
<a id="A1" runat="server" href='~/UserDetails.aspx?Id=' + <%= Session["UserId"].ToString() %>>
<span>Home</span></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <li class="active ">
        <a href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/UserDetails.aspx?Id=") + Session["UserId"].ToString() %>'>
           Home
        </a>
    </li>
```

EDIT: Added Page.ResolveUrl and removed ';' at the end of ToString()

Comment: nope doesnt work "The resource cannot be found."   Also i had to remove the ; between () and %. Since it said " ) Expected" .

Comment: Make sure session variable UserId is not null.

Comment: Yeahh the thats not the problem , the userid works perfectly.

Comment: The error "The resource cannot be found." is a 404 page not found error. Are you sure that's the error that is being thrown? I just tried it and it works on my end. I set a dummy value of Session["UserId"] on Page_Load event.

Comment: okay i resloved the problem with the 404 error, now its saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when i click the button

Comment: The object reference not set to an instance of an object comes from the session variable UserId which is null. If you put string dummy = Session["UserId"].ToString(); in the Page_Load event, i bet it will throw an exception on that line.